# How to get Word Count using Google Vision OCR API by Python?

Tags: python, google-vision

I want to scan a `image` document and graph the `word` from image and I also want to get the `word count`. Is this possible by using `Google Vision API`?

I didn’t seen any related information regarding word count within their documentation. If anybody achieved this before, please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted example from the sample available in [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-vision-api-python/index.html?index=..%2F..index#7):

```
from google.cloud import vision

def count_words(str):
    ls1 = str.split()
    return len(ls1)


image_uri = 'gs://cloud-vision-codelab/otter_crossing.jpg'

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
image = vision.types.Image()
image.source.image_uri = image_uri

response = client.text_detection(image=image)

for text in response.text_annotations:
    print(text.description)
    print(count_words(text.description))
```

Fair suggestion from my side: Give the other OCR libraries a shot as well.